# Using a class nested in a generic class as type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inner-classes, type-parameter

Having the following definition:

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public class Nested { }
}
```

And given that ECMA ref §25.1 states:

> Any class nested inside a generic class declaration or a generic
>   struct declaration (§25.2) is itself a generic class declaration,
>   since type parameters for the containing type shall be supplied to
>   create a constructed type.

I understand that `Nested` requires the type parameter in order to be instantiated.

I can obtain the generic `Type` with `typeof`:

```
var type = typeof(Generic<>.Nested); 
// type.FullName: Namespace.Generic`1+Nested
```

Is there any way I can use it as a type parameter for a generic method such as the following?

```
var tmp = Enumerable.Empty<Generic<>.Nested>(); 
// Error: Unexpected use of an unbound generic
```

As stated before, from the ECMA specification I understand that all the type parameters must be satisfied before instancing but no objects are being created here. Furthermore, the `Nested` class does not make use of the type parameters in any way: I simply would like to define it nested for code organization purposes.

Comment: What would you *do* with an empty sequence of non-specified nested classes? I don't see any way around the limitation. The fact that `Nested` doesn't utilize `T` and that you're currently prototyping with an empty sequence do not appear to be relevant. For a fully constructible type for the sequence, you'll need to supply the type parameter.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram the example is poorly chosen, sorry. The actual motivation is defining message classes inside generic Akka.Net actors. Thus, I just want to define those nested classes where they belong, but they do not require type parameters in any way.

Comment: I assume you want to work with any instance (or list of) the nested class without regard to the containing outer class? I would suggest as an alternative to define an interface, have your nested class inherit from that interface, and then work via references (including lists) of that interface. Something like http://pastebin.com/xLQDKudb

Comment: Do you want to declare `var tmp = Enumerable.Empty<Generic<>.Nested>(); ` outside of the parent class? Otherwise `var tmp = Enumerable.Empty<Nested>();` should work.

Comment: Another approach is to create a builder function in your parent class that will build you an IEnumarable instance of your child class?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram that's an interesting work-around, however in this case I think it would bloat the code and I'd just rather move the class outside. My intention was to qualify the message (nested class) name with the actor (containing generic class) that will handle it just to make the code more expressive. I guess I'll have to move it outside and play with namespaces.

Comment: @DanielvanHeerden I want to use the nested class as a type parameter really, without specifying its containing class type parameters - and do so outside that containing class. Those solutions could be interesting if I were concerned about how to create the nested class objects, or if doing so from the containing class, thanks.

Comment: @jnovo I wonder if your main goal won't be achieved simply by putting the sub class next to the parent in the same namespace. The namespace is really what should be organising the code in the way you are talking about. You should really only be defining a class as a sub class it only the parent class is going to be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. As you said

> all the type parameters must be satisfied before instancing

and though no instance of `Generic<>.Nested` is actually generated

- the compiler does not know the semantics of `Empty` (so doesn't know that no instance of `Generic<>.Nested` is created)
- and the **main problem**: you *do* want to create an instance of `IEnumerabe<Generic<>.Nested>`, which would be a type with *"unsatisfied type parameters"*, too

Answer (score 0):

I think your main goal will probably be achieved simply by putting the sub class next to the parent in the same namespace.

The namespace is really what should be organising the code in the way you are talking about in the comments under your post.

You should really only be defining a class as a sub class it only the parent class is going to be using it.